# Disable powershell expansion of command's extension?

Tags: powershell

We have a lot of existing batch files that help with the running of different perl and ruby scripts.

A batch file (e.g. test.bat) would normally be invoked like:

$ test

and within the batch file, it will set some settings and finally try to run the corresponding script file (e.g. test.pl) like this:

```
perl -S "%0.pl" %*
```

All works with cmd.exe, but today, I decided to switch to PowerShell and found out that it expands the commands. So trying to run "test" will actually run  "Full\path\test.bat" and my script would complain that there is no file test.bat.pl.

Is there a way to prevent this command expansion? Rewriting all batch files is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to call cmd explicitly:

```
cmd /c test
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for, but it works and for lack of a better answer, i'm accepting yours. Thanks